# Understanding PHP URL

Tags: php

Very fundamental question

I have phplist project set-up in net beans. URL I am accessing is 
    http://example.com/admin/ and 
all the files are under list folder.
In debugging I can see that all the times execution starts from index.php file in lists folder. 
What I am not getting is how does the particular php file associated with URL gets executed. 
Meaning
    http://example.com/admin/ 
should execute admin.php, but how does the execution goes to admin.php

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you're asking but I did have experience with phplist several years ago.  Is there a .htaccess file in the root, admin, or list directories? It may be hidden on your operating system. If present, that file may be responsible for rewriting URLs internally.

Comment: This is not a PHP question. This is a system administration question. You should remove the PHP tag and list more information about your web server, and how it is configuired to index files.

Comment: Ok, I just downloaded a recent PHPList release and although .htaccess files exist, they are only defining directory permissions, no RewriteRule.

Comment: I got the answer. index.php in each folder is used as entry point. 
It might not be a direct php question but must for a php programmer to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

if you enter only the file path like you did, it runs the index.php file, if you want to run any file in the folder, append the filename to the path like this:  http://example.com/admin/admin.php

Comment: Thanks, got it. Every folder has index.php and its running when the respective folder URL is run.

Answer (score 1):

Typically with applications like this, all of the page accesses are routed through the index.php script, which examines the URL and maps/routes the request to the correct script based on what it contains.

A quick peek at the source of phplist makes it seem like that is indeed what is going on - look at the index.php for more detail.